# Unable to change screen saver of any user on a Macbook Pro

Tags: high-sierra, screensaver

I have recently taken over a 2017 MBP from a colleague. Apparently I was given a complete base re-install of OSX and upgraded to High Sierra, i.e. all previous custom configurations were reset. However I am unable to change my screen saver from Flurry, to any of the others provided by OSX e.g. Nat Geo.

I created another admin user (i.e. with same permissions) and tried it as that user, and still the same problem. I have full admin privileges and cannot change my screen saver, wow. Seems then this is a system issue, not user specific.

Have deleted `com.apple.screensaver.plist` from both my account and the system but no joy.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Check if you have a file at this path: `/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Computer Name.saver`. If yes, try after double clicking and installing it.

Comment: You might also need to delete: `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.screensaver.<UUID>.plist`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but these two suggestions above have not fixed the issue.